# Simple TypeScript Class gives TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I want to use class Literal from file Classes.tsx in file App.tsx but TypeScript returns a TypeError even if they're in the same file.
Works fine on [typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play).

```
// Classes.tsx
abstract class Expression {
  abstract val: boolean;
  abstract str: string;
}

class Literal extends Expression {
  val: boolean;
  constructor(value: boolean) {
    super();
    this.val = value;
  }
  get str(): string {
    return this.val ? "W" : "F";
  }
}
```

```
// App.tsx
import { Expression, Literal } from "./Classes";

let F: Literal = new Literal(false);
```

Error: `TypeError: Cannot set property str of #<Literal> which has only a getter`

Why?

Comment: Not certain but maybe it has to do with the fact that you haven't set a value for the abstract string field?

Comment: what if you define it as `abstract readonly str: string` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two solutions:

1. adding setter
2. change declaration to getter (from `abstract str: string;` to `abstract get str(): string;`